# How do I tell users that they can ask questions in Audio format?

Tags: intuition, selling-ux

My site is a legal consultation platform. I am offering an option for users to ask questions in an audio format as well. I know that the way I'm doing it now is wrong because only 1% of the users tap that button and 0% actually submit an audio question.

When we set the audio as default, it was the main converting channel, and people didn't switch to the text.

Can you advise on what's the best way to convey to users the ability to switch between formats?
Thanks.
Below is how we do it today. (Notice the green mic)
And when you switch to audio:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have the total number of submissions (text + audio) gone down? Just because users favor one way doesn't mean there's a problem. Put another way, what's the "right" percentage of audio submissions and how do you know? What prompted switching the default from audio to text in the first place?

Comment: You might want to test this with users to find out what the issue is. Are people generally more comfortable with typing/editing when they know they have the choice (maybe your previous design didn't feel like a choice)? Do they worry that 60 seconds won't be long enough to talk through a problem? A think-aloud test could reveal why they're not opting for it.

Comment: Are you able to get a log of what devices your users access the application from? For e.g. via laptop, desktop, tablet, and/or phones?

Comment: My users are 80% mobile.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are on the right track! The design is clean and usable! Now back to your question. You said that when the audio version was presented to the user by default, then they would use it. However, when the text version is used by default, less than 1% actually switch to the audio. The objective here is to encourage users to record their question.

How about this: Instead of directly opening the text area or the audio recording button, give the user the ability to choose either one from the beginning. I have attached a quick wireframe to illustrate the idea:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to start on the audio consultation page so that people tend to use it more. An enhancement there could be to make the text icon feel more button-like.

Another approach altogether could be to combine the two and make the input audio/ text and audio input is converted to speech in front of the user so they can edit it too. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, the user can either post an Audio OR a Text question, not a combination. The button suggestion is good IMO, will give it a try.

Comment: If you make the user land on the text input page, the helper text could read : "Type the text or record audio"